# File `imakeidx.sty' not found

Tags: miktex, compiling, imakeidx

Since the last update of MiKTeX, I am experiencing an issue when compiling my work : it stops and the log file says :

```
! LaTeX Error: File `imakeidx.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.104 ^^M

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

This does not seem to be directly related to my preamble, since I have tried with minimal test documents and the same issue happens; moreover, my document used to compile properly until yesterday, without any change being made since to the preamble. I have removed and reinstalled MiKTeX 2.9 twice, with both basic and complete versions, and none of them worked, as the system does not find `imakeidx.sty`. Any idea of what is happening, and how to solve it ? Many thanks for any help provided.

Comment: The error message means that you do not have the `imakeidx` package installed in your MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: I Know that this is what the message is supposed to mean. But this is not the case : I have checked, and installed a complete version of MikTex, refreshed the FNDB, checked with the package manager that imakeidx is properly installed, and it is, and....it does not work !

Comment: I confirm it. It happened to me also. Somehow miktex update is buggy. I downloaded `imakeidx.sty` from CTAN and copied it to `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\imakeidx\ `. But last update of miktex said `going to remove 12 packages` and I didn't care. It means with some other packages too this problem may come. I am not sure which other packages it removed, though.

Comment: Yes ! It works that way, thank you Harish : I must add that once downloaded from CTAN, one has to run pdflatex on imakeidx.dtx (in ...MiKTex 2.9\tex\latex\imakeidx\) for imakeidx.sty to be produced. Compiling works fine now.

Comment: I've already opened a bug ticket for that: http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2282/

Comment: @karlkoeller: it has been marked as fixed thanks to you. I can't get it from the repositories yet but it should be up soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awnser simply turns comments into an awnser. Creit goes to the comment authors

It is a miktex bug that can worked around as @HarishKumar describes:

Build the package from [ctan] (run pdflatex on `imakeidx.dtx`), and place `makeidx.sty` in the corresponding folder of your tex tree (MiKTex 2.9\tex\latex\imakeidx).

@karlkoeller reported this as a bug which has been resolved. It is not availalbe in the miktex updates right now, but should be rather soon.